# Why do I get a ValueError in my Kafka Consumer if I seek to another position?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I'm using python 3.9.16 and kafka-python version 2.0.2. I'm running on my Macbook Pro IOS 11.6.5.

I'm still getting my feet wet with Kafka so it's entirely possible I'm doing things the wrong way.

What I'm trying to do is test seeking to offsets with my consumer in case something doesn't get processed and I have to go back and re-read a message.

Anyway, I keep running into this error message.  I'm not even sure why it's happening because sometimes I can process the offset and it works fine, other times, it gives me this message:

```
ValueError: Error encountered when attempting to convert value: b'' to struct format: '<built-in method unpack of _struct.Struct object at 0x10bb669f0>', hit error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

When it's working, I can see this in pdb, which kinda proves that the values are present in the topic for me to consume:

```
(Pdb) 
> /Users/username/kafka/tkCons.py(41)<module>()
-> print ("{}, {}".format(blah.offset, blah.value))
(Pdb) 
10, b'{"number": 10}'
> /Users/username/kafka/tkCons.py(40)<module>()
-> for blah in consumer:
(Pdb)
```

I wish I could narrow down what I'm doing during testing but I can't pin down what lines of code I added/commented out helps make it work or makes it give me the above error.
Since I'm not 100% sure what's happening under the hood, is me seeking around somehow affecting something in zookeeper?  What do I need to do to make whatever under the hood stuff happy?  Here's my code in case it matters.

```
from kafka import KafkaConsumer, TopicPartition

# To consume latest messages and auto-commit offsets
consumer = KafkaConsumer(#'my-topic333', 'my-topic222', 'my-topic',
                         group_id='my-group',
                         bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

myTP = TopicPartition('my-topic333', 0)
import pdb 
pdb.set_trace()

consumer.assign([myTP])
print ("this is the consumer assignment: {}".format(consumer.assignment()))
print ("before this is my position: {} ".format(consumer.position(myTP)))
consumer.seek(myTP, 50)
#consumer.seek_to_beginning()   
print ("after seeking this is my position: {} ".format(consumer.position(myTP)))

for blah in consumer:
    print ("{}, {}".format(blah.offset, blah.value))
```

Comment: You say you 'proved' there is a value by showing one value, but is there a value at the offset that fails? If you try to retrieve a value at a non-existent offset, it will fail.
So, depending on the retention policy on your Kafka cluster, lower offsets may have been discarded, and higher offsets may not have been created yet. Are you sure you are looking at a range that has values?

Comment: @MrE The Java API will automatically seek to the nearest available offset if seeking out of range. I assume Python would do the same? Or at least raise a more descriptive range error? The error seems more related to that the value is empty, or has less than 4 bytes, as the error says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `blah.value` could be `None`, but it should print None, then, not raise a ValueError related to deserialization... You need to show your full stacktrace and print the offset on a separate line from the value so that you can see where the error is actually happening, or look at any logs that include the previous successful offset...

> in case something doesn't get processed and I have to go back and re-read a message

I'd not suggest using seek for this.

Instead, make a failed processor raise a fatal exception, and stop your Python  process. Then, handle offset commits manually for any successfully processed data (or batch of offsets you're willing to tolerate duplicates for, assuming you're processing them in an idempotent way), meaning also disable auto offset commits. Then, when you do this, and restart the consumer group, the app will automatically pick back up after the last successfully processed offset, and no manual seeking is required.

> is me seeking around somehow affecting something in zookeeper?

Assign API does not use consumer groups, so not unless you also use subscribe and commit functions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about disabling auto offset commits.  Perhaps it's my inexperience with Kafka but for some reason, every time I restart the consumer, it starts back with the oldest message, which is why I'm messing with seek to try to tell the consumer to jump to the last consumed message and not start back at the beginning.

Comment: And thanks, from my test producer, the values are not None in this case but I see what you're saying, to handle that possibility that it can be None. In any case, I did what you suggested in my other question (update python to 3.11.4) and the problem with the ValueError seems to have gone away.  Now on to my new problem with starting at the beginning...grrr

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I experimented some more with what you advised.  Looks like for some reason the "enable_auto_commit=True" parameter when constructing my consumer doesn't work but if I run consumer.commit() after reading the message, THIS does what I need/want.

Comment: Auto commits should work, but I think it only commits every 500 offsets or so